# Simple terminology checker

Tags: windows, gratis, word-processor, spell-checker

I am looking for a simple tool that would check text for terminology based on a replacement list.

Example of a replacement definition:

- allowed: application
- disallowed: app; consider: application
- disallowed: program; consider: application
- allowed: bonus program
- disallowed: bounty program; consider: bonus program

Example text:

> Our app supports the bounty program.

Findings:

> error: app 
>   error: bounty program

Suggested text:

> Our application supports the bonus program.

Non-Finding:

> error: program

Note how the software has to consider longer terms over short terms, otherwise there would be too many false positives.

Requirements:

- simple editing of the replacement list with free tools or Microsoft Office
- machine readable format of the replacement list so that we can write tools that support the workflow
- run on Windows
- is free / open source
- finds errors as explained above
- color highlighting

  - red: error
  - green: recognized term
  - I'm looking for some sort of report, not a modification of the original file. It may be a temporary report displayed on the screen. No need to be saved.
- makes suggestions as explained above
- if multiple suggestions apply, let the user choose which one to take

I have already tried:

- [TermXAct](https://termtechnologies.com/tools-terminologiemanagement/terminologieprufung-mit-termxact/) (German), but a) it's commercial and b) does not prefer long terms over short ones and c) is not feaure-complete

Comment: "Color highlighting" — Are you asking for an output document (a report) that has this highlighting, or for the original document to be modified to use this highlighting?

Comment: @Kodiologist: thanks for the question. I'm looking for some sort of report. It may be a temporary report displayed on the screen. No need to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it in Python 3. This program has all the requested features except for color highlighting, because the Win32 console only supports color as of the Threshold 2 Update for Windows 10. Most of the complexity of the program is for handling the case of multiple suggestions.

```
 import sys, re, collections

 context_size = 30

 defs_path, doc_path = sys.argv[1:]

 defs = collections.defaultdict(list)
 with open(defs_path, 'rt') as o:
     for l in o:
         bad, _, good = l.strip().partition(' -> ')
         defs[bad].append(good)

 with open(doc_path, 'rt') as o:
     doc = o.read()

 def replacement_f(m):
     print('\nerror:', m.group())
     candidates = defs[m.group()]
     if len(candidates) == 1:
         print('Replacing with:', candidates[0])
         return candidates[0]
     print('There are multiple possible replacements.')
     print('Context:', re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', doc[
         max(m.start() - context_size, 0) :
         min(m.start() + context_size, len(doc))]))
     print('Candidates:', dict(enumerate(candidates)))
     while True:
        n = input('Enter a number: ')
        if n.isdigit() and int(n) < len(candidates):
            return candidates[int(n)]
 doc = re.sub(
     '|'.join(re.escape(bad) for bad in
         sorted(defs.keys(), key = len, reverse = True)),
     replacement_f,
     doc)

 print('\nResult:\n')
 print(doc)
```

Now suppose you have a file `defs.txt` like this:

```
app -> application
program -> application
bounty program -> bonus program
supports -> can use
supports -> has support for
```

and a file `input.txt` like this:

```
Our app supports the bounty program.
```

If the Python program is named `script.py`, you can run it with the command:

```
python3 script.py defs.txt input.txt
```

The result looks like this:

```
error: app
Replacing with: application

error: supports
There are multiple possible replacements.
Context: Our app supports the bounty program. 
Candidates: {0: 'can use', 1: 'has support for'}
Enter a number: 0

error: bounty program
Replacing with: bonus program

Result:

Our application can use the bonus program.
```

Comment: Wow, I knew it wasn't that hard to implement, but I'm surprised how short it actually can be. I'm in a training for the next 3 days. I will try the solution when I'm back in the office,